# I want to fetch the record for the user I am logged in only. Currently I can fetch the record of all the users . Please look into this problem

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

This is my Fetch Report Table Where I get all the records of my patient. This is Okay But I want all the records of a single patient at one time how can I do that?
Now, when I click on the patient report in my patient main panel the page for verification, opens where my patient's first name, contact, and blood group are matched from the database once that is successful my patient report table is displayed. Now what I want is that the table shows the data based on the first name that I enter in the verification view.

Now I have Attatched the verify.blade.php file and the edited code of controller as well as the route file, i.e. web.php related to these views. Kindly help me out with accessing the data of the patient who's firstname i enter in verification view. When I enter the name of this patient, it should fetch only the data of that patient.

> My Fetch Report Table (Blade) File:

```
 <body>
<center><h1>Patient Report <br>
                </h1></center>
<form >
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr  class="bg-danger text-light">
                <th>Patient First Name</th>
                <th>Patient Last Name</th>
                <th>Patient Address</th>
                <th>Patient Contact</th>
                <th>Patient BloodGroup</th>
                <th>Patient Date-Of-Birth</th>
                <th>Patient CNIC</th>
                <th>Patient Gender</th>
                <th>Patient Blood Pressure Reading</th>
                <th>Patient Temperature Reading</th>
                <th>Patient ECG Reading</th>
                <th>Patient Medical Record</th>
                <th>Payment Type</th>
                <th>Total Payment</th>
                <th>Remaining Payment</th>
            </tr>
            @if(isset($data))
            @foreach($data as $row)
            <tr  class="bg-secondary text-light">
            <td>{{$row->firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->address}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->contact}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->bloodgroup}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->dateofbirth}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->cnic}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->gender}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->bp}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->temp}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->ecg}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->prerecord}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->ptype}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->tpayment}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->rpayment}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </table>
        
        </form>
        <br>
```

> This is my verify.blade.php

```
<body>
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100">
        <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-85 p-r-85 p-t-55 p-b-55">
            <form action="{{url('/verify/fetch')}}" method="POST" class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w">
            @CSRF 
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-32">
                    Personal Details
                </span>
                <span class="txt1 p-b-11">
                    Username
                </span>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36" data-validate = "Username is required">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <span class="txt1 p-b-11">
                    Contact
                </span>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36" data-validate = "Email is required">
                    <input  class="input100" type="text" name="contact" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <span class="txt1 p-b-11">
                    Blood-Group
                </span>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36" data-validate = "Email is required">
                    <input  class="input100" type="text" name="bloodgroup" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-sb-m w-full p-b-48">
                    <div>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="d-flex align-items-center container-login100-form-btn">
                    <a class="login100-form-btn" >
                        <button type="submit" name="action"  class="login100-form-btn">
                            Verify
                        </button>
                    </a>
                
                </div>
            


            </form>
```

> This is my Controller Function where I use $data:

public function fetch(Request $req)

```
    {
            $firstname = $req->input('firstname');
            $contact=$req->input('contact');
            $bloodgroup=$req->input('bloodgroup');
            $data= DB::select('select id from patient_details where firstname=? and contact=? and bloodgroup=?',[$firstname,$contact,$bloodgroup]);
            if(count($data))
            {
                return redirect('report');
            }
            else
            {
                echo "failed";
            }
        }
        public function report()
        {
            $data = DB::table('patient_details')->where('patient_details.firstname','=','Bilal')
            ->join('pmedicalreadings','pmedicalreadings.id','patient_details.id')
            ->join('medrecords','medrecords.id','=','patient_details.id')
            ->join('payments','payments.id','=','patient_details.id')
            ->select('patient_details.firstname','patient_details.lastname','patient_details.address','patient_details.contact','patient_details.bloodgroup','patient_details.dateofbirth','patient_details.cnic','patient_details.gender','pmedicalreadings.bp','pmedicalreadings.temp','pmedicalreadings.ecg','medrecords.prerecord','payments.ptype','payments.tpayment','payments.rpayment')       
            
            ->get();
        
    

return view('report',compact('data'));
}
```

> This is the route:

```
Route::get('/verify', function () {
    return view('/verify');
});
    Route::get('/report','JoinController@report');
Route::post('verify/fetch', 'JoinController@report');
```

Thankyou in Advance!

Comment: Where is the code which assigns `$data` value?

Comment: That's just the (not so important) view, we'd need to see how you fetch `$data`. Please [edit] your question and paste that code

Comment: [On a sidenote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center): "_`<center>..</center>` is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it._"

Comment: Okay I'll add the controller and web files.

Comment: Sir, kindly take a look at the files I edited above. and he description too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem. For anyone facing similar issues now or in the future can peek from here and resolve their issue. The problem was one that I was not using left join in my controller, and not passing the $firstname variable using the $req variable. One more problem was with my verify.blade.php file where my firstname text field name was written as username which I changed back to the firstname and the problem got resolved. The route is the same and the report.blde.php file is also the same that's why I didn't add them.

> This is the blade file:

```
<body>
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100">
        <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-85 p-r-85 p-t-55 p-b-55">
            <form action="{{url('/verify/fetch')}}" method="POST" class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w">
            @CSRF 
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-32">
                    Personal Details
                </span>
                <span class="txt1 p-b-11">
                    Username
                </span>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36" data-validate = "Username is required">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="firstname" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <span class="txt1 p-b-11">
                    Contact
                </span>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36" data-validate = "Email is required">
                    <input  class="input100" type="text" name="contact" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <span class="txt1 p-b-11">
                    Blood-Group
                </span>
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36" data-validate = "Email is required">
                    <input  class="input100" type="text" name="bloodgroup" >
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-sb-m w-full p-b-48">
                    <div>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="d-flex align-items-center container-login100-form-btn">
                    <a class="login100-form-btn" >
                        <button type="submit" name="action"  class="login100-form-btn">
                            Verify
                        </button>
                    </a>
                
                </div>
            


            </form>
```

> This is my controller:

```
public function fetch(Request $req)
{
    
    $firstname = $req->input('firstname');
    $contact=$req->input('contact');
    $bloodgroup=$req->input('bloodgroup');
    $verify= DB::select('select id from patient_details where firstname=? and contact=? and bloodgroup=?',[$firstname,$contact,$bloodgroup]);
    if(count($verify))
    {
        return $this->report($req);
        
    }
    else
    {
        return response(['message' => 'Failed!'], 400);
    }
}
public function report(Request $request)
{
    $firstname = $request->input('firstname');
    $data = DB::table('patient_details')->where('patient_details.firstname','=',$firstname)
    
    ->join('pmedicalreadings','pmedicalreadings.id', '=', 'patient_details.id')
    ->leftjoin('medrecords','medrecords.id','=','patient_details.id')
    ->leftjoin('payments','payments.id','=','patient_details.id')
    ->select('patient_details.firstname','patient_details.lastname','patient_details.address','patient_details.contact','patient_details.bloodgroup','patient_details.dateofbirth','patient_details.cnic','patient_details.gender','pmedicalreadings.bp','pmedicalreadings.temp','pmedicalreadings.ecg','medrecords.prerecord','payments.ptype','payments.tpayment','payments.rpayment')       
    
    ->get();
    return view('report',compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if $data is your all-patients-array you can do something like this:

```
 $data = Model::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

if its not what you want then send your controller

> Here is the Code

```
 public function report()
{
    $data = DB::table('patient_details')
    ->join('pmedicalreadings','pmedicalreadings.id','patient_details.id')
    ->where('firstname', $Burhan)
    ->join('medrecords','medrecords.id','=','patient_details.id')
    ->join('payments','payments.id','=','patient_details.id')
    
    ->select('patient_details.firstname','patient_details.lastname','patient_details.address','patient_details.contact','patient_details.bloodgroup','patient_details.dateofbirth','patient_details.cnic','patient_details.gender','pmedicalreadings.bp','pmedicalreadings.temp','pmedicalreadings.ecg','medrecords.prerecord','payments.ptype','payments.tpayment','payments.rpayment')
    ->where('firstname', $Burhan)
    ->get();
    return view('report',compact('data'));
}
```

}

Comment: I have attached the controller.

Comment: try adding this after your select : ->where(''patient_details.user_id', auth()->user()->id);

Comment: if you have user_id in your patient_details table then it should work for you

Comment: Sir, I dont have user_id in patient_details table.

Comment: what you have in your table for user?

Comment: id, username, email, cnic, password and confirm password

Comment: ok! do you have id or username for special user that you want to show?
which one you have?

Comment: like if i fetch this table i only want a specific result not all the results in the database. What I'm trying to want is something like when I click fetch it will ask me my username and password and then show the fetched results of the table for the username I entered

Comment: so try this: ->where(''patient_details.username', $your_username_from_input);
put this after select and test

Comment: Sir, its just showing the table view not retrieving any data now.

Comment: ->where(''username', $your_username_from_input);
try this once after select and another time before first join and make sure you are entering username that you have in your table

Comment: it says, Undefined variable: Burhan

Comment: you should assign $burhan to what you are getting from user input
something like: $burhan = $request->input('username')

Comment: sir I have made some changes can you kindly take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public function report()
{
    $query = DB::table('patient_details')
    ->join('pmedicalreadings','pmedicalreadings.id','patient_details.id')
    ->join('medrecords','medrecords.id','=','patient_details.id')
    ->join('payments','payments.id','=','patient_details.id')
    ->select('patient_details.firstname','patient_details.lastname','patient_details.address','patient_details.contact','patient_details.bloodgroup','patient_details.dateofbirth','patient_details.cnic','patient_details.gender','pmedicalreadings.bp','pmedicalreadings.temp','pmedicalreadings.ecg','medrecords.prerecord','payments.ptype','payments.tpayment','payments.rpayment');

    $data['users'] = $query->get();
    $data['user'] = $query->where('user_id', auth()->getUserId())->get();

    return view('report',compact('data'));
}
```

You can use collection filter for current userID;

```
public function report()
{
    $currentUserId = auth()->getUserId();

    $users = DB::table('patient_details')
    ->join('pmedicalreadings','pmedicalreadings.id','patient_details.id')
    ->join('medrecords','medrecords.id','=','patient_details.id')
    ->join('payments','payments.id','=','patient_details.id')
    ->select('patient_details.firstname','patient_details.lastname','patient_details.address','patient_details.contact','patient_details.bloodgroup','patient_details.dateofbirth','patient_details.cnic','patient_details.gender','pmedicalreadings.bp','pmedicalreadings.temp','pmedicalreadings.ecg','medrecords.prerecord','payments.ptype','payments.tpayment','payments.rpayment')
    ->get();

    $data['users'] = $users;
    $data['user'] = collect($users)->filter(function ($item, $index) use ($currentUserId) {
       return $item->user_id == $currentUserId;
    });
```

Comment: BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::getUserId does not exist.

Comment: added ``use Auth;`` at the top of your model.

Comment: sir I have made some changes can you kindly take a look?